# How to edit notification in background came from Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app get notifications from Firebase but it came with no sound and app's icon.

In the method onMessageReceived(), I can edit notifications, but it didn't work in the background.

What is the solution?

Comment: will you add your code

Comment: 'code'@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent msgrcv = new Intent(this,MyServer.class);
        msgrcv.putExtra("message",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendBroadcast(msgrcv);

    }

Answer (score 0):

Send from your server:

```
  {
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Hello World!",
      "title" : "My app",
      "icon" : "myicon"
      "sound":"mysound"
    }

  }
```

The sound file must be in /res/raw/ and the icon in /res/drawable.

From Firebase console

[image]

Edit notification when your app has been killed is no posible, because android system handle notifications.

Comment: full example please

Comment: You only need send json from your server  with parameters sound and icon or from firebase with this parameters and system android   in notification will play sound and show your icon that your save  in /res/raw/ and in /res/drawable.

Comment: Do you see whatsapp ?? I want to make my notifications this

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this code.

```
 private void showNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound)
{
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.addLine(message);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: where can I use this

Comment: you can use this code in your on onMessageReceived() method.

Comment: but onMessageReceived() method not called in background

Comment: firebase sends notification to onMessageReceived() and then we can edit the notification by using given code.By background  if you mean to make the changes in Firebase itself, then as per my knowledge, it is not possible to edit there.

Comment: you can edit notifications in onMessageReceived() only.

Comment: but onMessageReceived() not called in background